# PostgreSQL trying to select json array value

Tags: postgresql

I have the following json array stored in a column in my postgres db. I am trying to write a query to get all rows by country **name**.

The query will execute but cannot get it to return any values.

The column name is `sources` and is of json array type.

**Example value**

```
[{
    "name": "Albania",
    "type": "domain",
    "order": 2
},{
    "name": "Samoa",
    "type": "domain",
    "order": 3
},{
    "name": "United States",
    "type": "domain",
    "order": 4
}]
```

Here is the query I'm trying to run:

```
 SELECT * from my_table,
        json_array_elements(sources->'name') elem
            where elem->>'name' = 'Samoa';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM my_table t
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM json_array_elements(t.sources) jae (e)
                            WHERE jae.e->>'name' = 'Samoa');
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it correct.  The problem is that you specified 'name' one time too often.  sources doesn't have a top level key named 'name' (because it is an array, it doesn't have string keys), so that gives 'null', which can't be unnested.  So:

```
SELECT * from my_table,
        json_array_elements(sources) elem
            where elem->>'name' = 'Samoa';
```

However, if you don't need the specific element which contains the match as a separate column, then you can use the containment operator to get rid of the join altogether.

```
select * from my_table where sources::jsonb @> '[{"name":"Samoa"}]';
```